# Get-DnsServerForwarder in WinSrv2012R2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, mmc

Can anyone tell me why when I execute this Powershel cmdlet I can see a DNS forwarder that I  inserted earlier (also using PS) but I can't see it on the DNS management console?

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM> Stop-Service dns
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM> Start-Service dns
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM> nslookup www.contoso.com
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.contoso.com
Address:  172.16.0.100

PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM> ping  www.contoso.com

Pinging www.contoso.com [172.16.0.100] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.16.0.11: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 172.16.0.11: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 172.16.0.11: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 172.16.0.11: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 172.16.0.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM>
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM>
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM>
PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM> Get-DnsServerForwarder


UseRootHint        : True
Timeout(s)         : 3
EnableReordering   : True
IPAddress          : 172.16.0.10
ReorderedIPAddress : 172.16.0.10



PS C:\Users\administrator.ADATUM>
```

DNS console screenshot = https://www.amazon.it/clouddrive/share/GyoRHfTQ99z60h5jo5wbCyjYbj4DG2vND27E65HKuXQ

Comment: i have set the forwarder with this command: Set-DnsServerForwarder –IPAddress '172.16.0.10' –PassThru

Answer (score 0):

The server updated the forwarder list, i think that was needed a ping  command (or nslookup) to a forwarder's zone.